# Destructuring of a vector

Tags: vector, common-lisp, destructuring

I am using a function from an external library returning a vector of four numbers and I want to access these values directly like it would be possible with `destructuring-bind`. See this pointless example:

```
(defun a-vector ()
  (vector 1 2 3 4))

(defun a-list ()
  (list 1 2 3 4))

(destructuring-bind (a b c d)
    (a-list)
  (format t "~D ~D ~D ~D~%" a b c d))

(destructuring-bind (a b c d)
    (coerce (a-vector) 'list)
  (format t "~D ~D ~D ~D~%" a b c d))
```

If I `coerce` the `vector` into a `list` it is possible and as performance isn't a problem here, it is maybe fine. But I was wondering if there is a more simple way?

Answer (score 7):

You can bind variables to each cell as follows:

```
(defmacro with-aref ((&rest indices) array &body body)
  (let ((a (gensym)))
    `(let ((,a ,array))
       (symbol-macrolet
           ,(loop
               for n from 0
               for i in indices 
               collect (list i `(aref ,a ,n)))
         ,@body))))
```

You would use it as follows:

```
(with-aref (w x y z) vec
  (setf w (+ x y z)))
```

---

With a bit more work, you can also support indices and different categories of accessors. Let's say each binding is a triple `(i n k)` where `i` is an identifier, `n` a number (or nil) that represents the numerical index and `k` is either `:place`,  `:value` or nil; `:place` binds the symbol with `symbol-macrolet`, `:value` just binds it with `let`.

First, let's help the user by providing shortcut notations:

- `x` stands for `(x nil nil)`
- `(x o)` either stands for `(x o nil)` or `(x nil o)`, depending on whether option `o` is a number or a symbol (at macroexpansion time).

Besides, we may want to automatically ignore the `nil` identifier, the empty symbol `||` or symbols starting with an underscore (e.g. `_`, `_var`).

Here is the normalization function:

```
(defun normalize-index (index)
  (flet ((ret (i n k)
           (let ((ignored (or (null i)
                              (string= i "")
                              (char= #\_ (char (string i) 0)))))
             (list (if ignored (gensym) i) n k ignored))))
    (let ((index (alexandria:ensure-list index)))
      (typecase index
        (null (ret nil nil nil))
        (cons (destructuring-bind (i &optional n (k nil kp)) index
                (if kp
                    (ret i n k)
                    (etypecase n
                      (symbol (ret i nil n))
                      ((integer 0) (ret i n nil))))))))))
```

We can apply this normalization to a list of indices, and keep track of ignored symbols:

```
(defun normalize (indices)
  (loop
     for i in indices
     for norm = (normalize-index i)
     for (index number kind ignore) = norm
     collect norm into normalized
     when ignore
     collect index into ignored
       finally (return (values normalized ignored))))
```

Then, we take care of `nil` numbers in normalized entries. We want the indices to increase from the last used index, or be given explicitly by the user:

```
(defun renumber (indices)
  (loop
     for (v n k) in indices
     for next = nil then (1+ index)
     for index = (or n next 0)
       collect (list v index k)))
```

For example:

```
(renumber (normalize '(a b c)))
((A 0 NIL) (B 1 NIL) (C 2 NIL))

(renumber (normalize '((a 10) b c)))
((A 10 NIL) (B 11 NIL) (C 12 NIL))

(renumber (normalize '((a 10) (b 3) c)))
((A 10 NIL) (B 3 NIL) (C 4 NIL))
```

We do the same for the kind of variable we bind:

```
(defun rekind (indices)
  (loop
     for (v n k) in indices
     for next = nil then kind
     for kind = (or k next :place)
     collect (list v n kind)))
```

For example:

```
(rekind (normalize '(a b c)))
((A NIL :PLACE) (B NIL :PLACE) (C NIL :PLACE))

(rekind (normalize '(a (b :value) c)))
((A NIL :PLACE) (B NIL :VALUE) (C NIL :VALUE))
```

Finally, all those steps are combined in `parse-indices`:

```
(defun parse-indices (indices)
  (multiple-value-bind (normalized ignored) (normalize indices)
    (values (rekind (renumber normalized))
            ignored)))
```

Finally, the macro is as follows:

```
(defmacro with-aref ((&rest indices) array &body body)
  (multiple-value-bind (normalized ignored) (parse-indices indices)
    (labels ((ignored (b) (remove-if-not #'ignoredp (mapcar #'car b)))
             (ignoredp (s) (member s ignored)))
      (loop
         with a = (gensym)
         for (i n k) in normalized
         for binding = `(,i (aref ,a ,n))
         when (eq k :value) collect binding into values
         when (eq k :place) collect binding into places
         finally (return
                   `(let ((,a ,array))
                     (let ,values
                       (declare (ignore ,@(ignored values)))
                       (symbol-macrolet ,places
                         (declare (ignore ,@(ignored places)))
                         ,@body))))))))
```

For example:

```
(let ((vec (vector 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)))
  (prog1 vec
    (with-aref ((a 2) (b :value) c _ _ d (e 0) (f 1)) vec
      (setf a (list a b c d e f)))))
```

The above is macroexpanded as:

```
(LET ((VEC (VECTOR 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)))
  (LET ((#:G1898 VEC))
    (LET ((#:G1901 VEC))
      (LET ((B (AREF #:G1901 3))
            (C (AREF #:G1901 4))
            (#:G1899 (AREF #:G1901 5))
            (#:G1900 (AREF #:G1901 6))
            (D (AREF #:G1901 7))
            (E (AREF #:G1901 0))
            (F (AREF #:G1901 1)))
        (DECLARE (IGNORE #:G1899 #:G1900))
        (SYMBOL-MACROLET ((A (AREF #:G1901 2)))
          (DECLARE (IGNORE))
          (LET* ((#:G19011902 #:G1901)
                 (#:NEW1 (LIST (AREF #:G1901 2) B C D E F)))
            (FUNCALL #'(SETF AREF) #:NEW1 #:G19011902 2)))))
    #:G1898))
```

It produces the following result

```
#(0 1 (2 3 4 7 0 1) 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

coredump's answer is lovely.  This is a variant of it which binds variables rather than accessors, and also lets you optionally specify indices.  So

```
(with-vector-elements ((a 3) b) x
  ...)
```

will bind `a` to the result of `(aref x 3)` and `b` to the result of `(aref x 4)`, for instance.

This is really only useful over coredump's answer if you're intending to (a) not write back to the vector and (b) use the bindings a lot, so you want to avoid a lot of possible `aref`s (which I don't think compilers can generally optimize away without some fairly strong assumptions).

```
(defmacro with-vector-elements ((&rest indices) vector &body forms)
  (let ((canonical-indices
         (loop with i = 0
               for index in indices
               collect (etypecase index
                         (symbol
                          (prog1 
                              `(,index ,i)
                            (incf i)))
                         (cons
                          (destructuring-bind (var idx) index
                            (assert (and (symbolp var) 
                                         (typep idx '(and fixnum (integer 0))))
                                (var idx) "Invalid index spec")
                            (prog1
                                index
                              (setf i (1+ idx))))))))
        (vname (gensym "V")))
    `(let ((,vname ,vector))
       (let ,(loop for (var index) in canonical-indices
                   collect `(,var (aref ,vname ,index)))
         ,@forms))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a package called `metabang-bind` - with nickname `bind` - in which the function `bind` can handle much more destructuring situations:

```
(ql:quickload :metabang-bind)
(in-package :metabang-bind)

(bind ((#(a b c) #(1 2 3)))
  (list a b c))
;; => (1 2 3)
```

If not using `in-package`, you can call the function as `bind:bind`.
The function `bind` you can think of roughly as a `destructuring-let*` (similar idea to clojure's `let`, however not so clean in syntax but understandable because it has also to handle structs and classes and also `values`).
All the other use cases it can handle are described [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/metabang-bind/user-guide.html).